# Starting ggplot x-axis at 0 when there is no data with 0 values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the number of unique detections per day throughout the year.
I had data that looked like this.

[image]

I summarized the number of unique detections per day using these codes

```
unique_day <- data %>% group_by(Day,tag) %>% filter(Date==min(Date)) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup()
```

```
sum <- unique_day %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Detections=n())
```

I then ended up with a dataframe like this

[image]

I then plot with this code

```
sum[year(sum$Date)==2016,] %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Date,y=Detections))+
  theme_bw(base_size = 16,base_family = 'serif')+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank())+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '1 month',date_labels = "%b",
                   limits = c(as.POSIXct('2016-01-01'),as.POSIXct("2016-12-01")))+
  ggtitle('DIS 2016')+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  xlab("Date")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0,5))
```

And get a plot like this
[image]

I cant seem to get the plot to start at 0... I figure it always starts at 1 because there are no 0 values for detections... I only have a data frame summarizing the days when there was detections, not when there was not detections. I have tried using ylim, scale_y_continuous and coord_cartesian... any ideas?

Any ideas?

Comment: You could create a data.frame with all missing days and value 0 and combine those two.

Comment: I thought about that but also am not the most expereinced in r and can not think of how to do that either.

Comment: What about if you replace `sum <- unique_day %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Detections=n())` with `sum <- unique_day %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Detections=n() - 1)` ?

Comment: This does produce zero values but lowers the detection count each day by 1 which I dont want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to get to your problem:

```r
df_null <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2015/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 365), 
                      Detections = 0)
```

For the year 2015 we create a data.frame containing all days with value 0. Suppose your data.frame looks like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(Date = c(as.Date("2015/06/07"), as.Date("2015/06/08"), as.Date("2015/12/12")), 
                 Detections = 1:3)
```

Using `dplyr` we combine those two data.frames and summarize the values:

```r
df %>%
  bind_rows(df_null) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(Detections = sum(Detections))
```

Finally you can get your plot using your `ggplot2`-code.